# NullPointer when using reflection to invoke a static method

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to invoke a private static method declared in a Class .

```
Class bridgeClass = Class.forName("MyClassName");
Method method = bridgeClass .getDeclaredMethod("isResourcePotentiallyOnPath" , new Class[]{String.class, List.class});
method.setAccessible(true);
```

and then,

```
Object [] args = new Object[2];
args[0] = "SomeResource"
args[1] = null; //by default i want to pass in null here

boolean returnValue = (Boolean)method.invoke(null, args);
```

I see that method is not null but method.invoke causing null pointer somewhere down the stack

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

What am i doing wrong??

Thanks

EDIT :

Here is the method that i am trying to invoke

```
private static boolean isResourcePotentiallyOnPath(String aFullyQualifiedName, List aClassPath){
        System.out.println("yahoo.. reached here finally");
        Jsr199FileManager fileManager = Jsr199FileManager.getInstance(jvmHomeForJars, aClassPath);
        return fileManager.isResourcePotentiallyOnPath(aFullyQualifiedName);
    }
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. just edited the post.. I am getting a Class instance first by doing Class.forName("StringRepresentationOfMyClass");

Comment: I'm 90% sure the first parameter you send it `method.invoke(null, args);` Needs to be an instance of that class. so something like `method.invoke(THATCLASS.newInstance(), args);`

Comment: also changed args[1] = new ArrayList() , but that doesnt stop the null pointer

Comment: @3kings : i am trying to invoke a private static method.. I am pretty sure that i need to pass in null as the first argument

Comment: can you post MyClassName class in the Question?

Comment: @UUDI : Any specific part of this class definition you want me to post.. The class itself is quite huge

Comment: The method you are trying to invoke would do.

Comment: @Tibrogargan : i have System.out.println statements (and debug pointers)  in my isResourcePotentiallyOnPath which i never see them in my console

Comment: Your reflective code looks line. Are you sure that NPE isn't thrown inside your method? Don't you have some `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at ...` which points to line which throws NPE? Try maybe to call that method directly (without reflection with same parameters).

Comment: Can you add `System.out.println(method.toString());` below `Method method...` run and paste the result

Comment: @TungD.Nguyen : toString :  private boolean com.abc.jsr199.Jsr199Bridge.isResourcePotentiallyOnPath(java.lang.String,java.util.List)

Comment: yes i did setAccessible(true) .. supprising,, the toString doesnt think that its a static method!!

Comment: try `args = new Object[] { "SomeResource" }; // no second arg`.   This should have no effect, but ... maybe

Comment: @Tibrogargan : nope didnt work

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html shows invoke() has elipsis arguments, so try invoke(null, "SomeResource", null);

Comment: @Tibrogargan : thanks for persisting ... but nope it doesnt work.. what i suspect is that toString on method doesnt think that the method is static.. not sure why thats the case

Comment: UPDATE : I was able to access another static method defined on the same class without any issues.. May be there is some deployment issue with this newly created static method or something like that.

Comment: @Barry Was that method also private?